# Would this multi-touch work?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, android-xml

So I was just messing with my android manifest file, and somehow I forgot what I did, and I messed something up.

so the error it is showing in eclipse is this

Element type "application" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

and I think because of that my R.java file is gone too...

If someone could find that mistake, I'd bow to them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.zunairgames.zunair"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".GFXSurface"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.zunairgames.zunair.GFXSURFACE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: close ur application tag

android:label="@string/app_name" >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application tag lacks a `>` at the end.
It should be like this:

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name" >
```